# When I try to Launch IE browser I am getting below Exception

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, automation

**Listening on port 6942
Jul 23, 2018 12:50:22 PM org.openqa.selenium.os.UnixProcess checkForError
SEVERE: **org.apache.commons.exec.ExecuteException: Process exited with an error: 1 (Exit value: 1)
Exception in thread "main"**

> org.openqa.selenium.remote.UnreachableBrowserException: Could not
>   start a new session. Possible causes are invalid address of the remote
>   server or browser start-up failure.

My Selenium Code

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
     Runtime.getRuntime().exec("Taskkill /IM IEDriverServer.exe /F");

     Excel_Reader e=new Excel_Reader(System.getProperty("user.dir")+"\\Company Creation Testdata.xlsx");

     System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver",System.getProperty("user.dir")+"\\IEDriverServer.exe");
     DesiredCapabilities capability = DesiredCapabilities.internetExplorer();
     capability.setBrowserName("internetExplorer");
     WebDriver d=new InternetExplorerDriver();
     d.manage().deleteAllCookies();

     d.get("https://10.150.7.32/dm-web/");
     Thread.sleep(1000);
```

Comment: Share your trial code and explain your expectation exactly.
Refer [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Could you briefly explain about your issue by modifying your question. The code and console alone not sufficient all the time.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change your browser name in your capabilities by "internet explorer"

Actual : capability.setBrowserName("internetExplorer");
 Change to : capability.setBrowserName("internet explorer");

Hope this will work for you..